# Invalid radius value in BlurMask Ffmpeg

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I'm using `boxblur` filter to blur specific area of video using cropping library, when i fire command sometimes it works well but sometimes it's showing me error.
Command and error are as below:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00 -t 02:43 -i input.mp4 
-filter_complex crop=28:24:20:14,boxblur=25[fg];[0:v][fg]overlay=20:14,
-vcodec libx264 output.mp4
```

This is throwing error - `Invalid luma_param radius value 25, must be >= 0 and <= 12`

In this command `crop=...` can be vary according to user need and `boxblur=25` is static.
So, if the error is related to `boxblur` then the question is why sometimes it works or if this was not the problem then what is the problem and solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

boxblur value must be less than or equal to the lesser input dimension (width or height) divided by 2. By input I am referring to the input given to boxblur: which in your case is coming from the crop filter. So if `crop=28:24` then boxblur max value is 12. If `crop=20:100` then boxblur max value is 10.

Solution is to use boxblur before crop:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00 -t 02:43 -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "boxblur=25,crop=28:24:20:14[fg];[0:v][fg]overlay=20:14" -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

Comment: Currently i tried to use boxblur before crop and it worked,Thank you..