# I've got 2 areas to blur – How to reuse the same filter?

Tags: ffmpeg

I understand this command to blur one area:

```
$ ffmpeg -i ACCT.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[0v]crop=850:100:140:175,boxblur=10[fg]; [0v][fg]overlay=140:175[v]" \
-map "[v]" \
blurredVideo.mp4
```

How to blur another area at the same time? Or, simply put, how to use multiple time the **same** filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i ACCT.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[0:v]crop=850:100:140:175,boxblur=10[blur1];[0:v]crop=100:50:100:50,boxblur=10[blur2]; [0:v][blur1]overlay=140:175[bg];[bg][blur2]overlay=50:50" \
-c:a copy \
blurredVideo.mp4
```

See **Multiple blurs over specific areas (without a mask)** in [FFmpeg - Apply blur over face](https://superuser.com/a/901705) for another example.

Comment: I tried to apply the following code, but ffmpeg reports "[Parsed_boxblur_3 @ 0x7fb5ed512080] Invalid chroma_param radius value 10, must be >= 0 and <= 7
[Parsed_boxblur_3 @ 0x7fb5ed512080] Failed to evaluate filter params: -22". It seems it's no longer possible with recent ffmpeg version (e.g. 4.4) to use this code to blur more than two areas. Code:
"[0:v]crop=50:50:20:10,boxblur=10[b0]; \
 [0:v]crop=iw:30:(iw-ow)/2:ih-oh,boxblur=10[b1]; \
 [0:v]crop=100:100:120:80,boxblur=10[b2]; \
 [0:v][b0]overlay=20:10[ovr0]; \
 [ovr0][b1]overlay=(W-w)/2:H-h[ovr1]; \
 [ovr1][b2]overlay=120:80"

Comment: @Faxopita See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65268791/